# Datascraping with BeatufilSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect "SMILES" codes of molecules from www.chemspider.com web site.
For instance, I would like to search the ChemSpider database with keyword "peroxide"
and it returns a table of results and subpages

[image: e]

So as you see each subpage with links above contains data of molecules.
I started with BeautifulSoup module but I have no idea how to move from there for example how can access the "2" page of the table?
Also sometimes these results come folded, just shows header of each row in the table. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider using their [API](https://developer.rsc.org/)

Comment: thank you for the comment. I did actually but their API does not allow partial searches.

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: @dundaryilmaz I had a look at the site. You may need selenium for your web scraping to work. Selenium can do the clicking page by page.